# calculate time with flag/status in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, datetime, date-difference

Please help me in query mysql.
How to calculate time from date_in with (ON/OFF) status.
sample data like this :

```
------------------------------
status  |      date_in         
------------------------------
ON      | 2017-10-27 23:30:37
ON      | 2017-10-28 01:08:40
ON      | 2017-10-28 01:10:43
OFF     | 2017-10-28 01:15:51
OFF     | 2017-10-28 01:26:28
ON      | 2017-10-28 01:30:33
ON      | 2017-10-28 02:00:15
------------------------------
```

and the result wants like this :

```
-----------------------------------------------
status  |      date_in        |  diff(hh:mm:ss)
-----------------------------------------------
ON      | 2017-10-27 23:30:37 | ON:00:00:00
ON      | 2017-10-28 01:08:40 | ON:01:38:03
ON      | 2017-10-28 01:10:43 | ON:00:02:03
OFF     | 2017-10-28 01:15:51 | OFF:00:00:00
OFF     | 2017-10-28 01:26:28 | OFF:00:10:17
ON      | 2017-10-28 01:30:33 | ON:00:00:00
ON      | 2017-10-28 02:00:15 | ON:00:29:42
------------------------------------------------
```

ON : 00:00:00 + 01:38:03 + 00:02:03 + 00:00:00 + 00:29:42 
= 02:09:48 / 2 hour, 9 minute, 48 second

OFF : 00:00:00 + 00:10:17  
= 00:10:17 / 0 hour, 10 minute, 17 second

Thankyou so much for help me...

dede.tar.gz@gmail.com

Comment: Where is your query?

Answer (score 0):

to count the timediff, u need to differentiate two timestamp.. but your question is not clear enough..

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('2009-05-18 15:45:57.005678','2009-05-18 13:40:50.005670');
```

u have the date_in.. to get the time different u need date_out to get the different value.